# Localization for angular 7 app using users language+country

Tags: javascript, html, angular, localization, internationalization

I have to localise my angular app with full locale capability like en-US, fr-FR, sv-SE.

The issue is that with locale = window.navigator.language; I am getting only language of the browser but not country.

I have researched a lot but not getting any definite answer for the same.
Is there any way I can get the the full locale being used for the app.

Thank you,
Tanisha

Comment: Check if it helps you: https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-detect-the-location-of-your-websites-visitor-using-javascript-92f9e91c095f

Comment: Thank you. This helps a lot. I was thinking of going in the same direction but didn't had any reference.